# Window 8 Frame navigation events

Tags: windows-8

I need to hook into the frame navigation events. How and when should I hook into the frame navigation events?
I tried In the constructor of a page but it seems the frame has not been created yet.
Thanks

Comment: try to be more specific : which technology ?

Answer (score 0):

If you placed the Frame in a page, then try hooking it in Page.OnNavgatedTo event and unhook it in Page.OnNavigatedFrom.